# Can I display second level up related fields in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

Lets say I have a three tier model as below, where posts are in categories which are then in categories. I'd like to get the Posts page in the Admin panel to display both the sub category and category that each post belongs to. And ideally let me filter by both. So far I can only get the Admin panel to work up one relationship level. So I can display and filter by the sub_category but when I add the category I get an error.

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class Posts(models.Model):
     title=models.CharField(max_length=15)
     sub_category=models.ForeignKey(Subcategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
     def __str__(self): 
         return self.title
```

Admin.py:

```
class PostsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('name',)
    list_display = ('name','id','sub_category', 'sub_category__category.name', )
    exclude = ('sort',)
    list_filter = ['sub_category','sub_category__category']
    search_fields = ['name']
admin.site.register(Posts, PostsAdmin)
```

Error is something like this:

```
<class 'journal.admin.PostsAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[4]' refers to 'sub_category__category', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PostsAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'journal.Admin'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a method on your admin class that returns the category for each post then reference this in `list_display`

```
class PostsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name','id','sub_category', 'category')

    def category(self, obj):
        return obj.sub_category.category.name
```

You could also add this method to the post model rather than the model admin

Comment: Thanks. I had to remove the obj when adding to models, so I added:

`def category(self):
        return self.sub_category.category.name`

Works now to make the category appear when viewing posts. But Admin won't allow me to add a method to the filters. Not a big deal but if there was a solution to that also, then that would be perfect.

Comment: sub_category__category__name may work in the search fields